# Prepend a word to all ajax urls by some configuration change in rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax

I have a rails app in which I have used ajax calls with some url. I want to append project name to the ajax urls.  One way is to edit all urls. Is there any other simpler way to do the same?

Comment: can you show here what you tried?

Comment: I want to run my rails app at http:localhost:3000/project_name instead of http:localhost:3000. So I made some changes in the routes files and the application is accessible as long as I am not using any ajax calls. I tried putting config.action_controller.relative_url_root = '/project_name' in development.rb file. But it's not working

Comment: Use `namespace` or `scope` in your `routes.rb`. See http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html

Comment: http://apidock.com/rails/ActionController/AbstractRequest/relative_url_root%3D/class

Comment: Max, I have added scope in routes.rb and that's how project_name is added to all the routes and it's expecting project_name before all the ajax urls. I don't want to edit all ajax urls manually.

Answer (score 0):

To prepend a word (let it be project_name) to all ajax calls in application write the following code in a js file:

```
$.ajaxSetup({
    beforeSend: function(data, settings) {
        var url = "/project_name"+ settings.url;
        settings.url = url;

    }
});
```

Comment: I tried some configuration changes in rails configuration file. It helped changing routes but not in appending a word in Ajax urls.So, I have looked for catching all Ajax request and modifying the url  with minimal code change.